# How to do loose coupling of button pressed and released events in Xamarin.Forms with Prism?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, prism

For my current project I need to capture button pressed and release events in Xamarin.Forms. But I want to keep things loosely coupled using Prism.

At first I used the Command property of the , like so:

```
<Button x:Name="ButtonForward" Command="{Binding MoveUpCommand}" />
```

But the Command property only fires when the button is released. To make seperate pressed and released actions I used the events in XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="ButtonForward" Pressed="ButtonForward_Pressed" Released="ButtonMove_Released"/>
```

And called the Commands manually in the event handlers in code behind:

```
private void ButtonMove_Released(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var vm = BindingContext as DirectControlViewModel;
            if (vm.MoveStopCommand.CanExecute(null))
                vm.MoveStopCommand.Execute(null);
        }

        private void ButtonForward_Pressed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var vm = BindingContext as DirectControlViewModel;
            if (vm.MoveUpCommand.CanExecute(null))
                vm.MoveUpCommand.Execute(null);
        }
```

The problem is that it isn't loosely coupled anymore, since the View now has to know its ViewModel.
Is there a way to have a button that does have seperate commands for pressed and released events, keeping the View and ViewModel loosely coupled? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why not use a behavior, as in normal (wpf-)xaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the EventToCommandBehavior on the Button. This will allow you take advantage of any Event on anything you're working with and Execute a Command when the event is fired.

```
<Button>
  <Button.Behaviors>
    <prism:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Pressed"
                                  Command="{Binding PressedCommand}" />
    <prism:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Released"
                                  Command="{Binding ReleasedCommand}" />
  </Button.Behaviors>
</Button>
```

Note there are additional properties that you can utilize if you have some sort of Parameter that you would like to pass the Command which may be a property in the EventArgs, or something else entirely that you'd like to bind to or specify.